# Duplicar <div> sem duplicar o JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3, javascript-eventos

Preciso da seguinte ajuda: consegui juntar dois códigos que achei na internet, e editei a formatação a meu gosto.

Tenho uma galeria com imagens e overflow na horizontal, meu código funciona, porém  preciso repetir a div completa uma ou mais vezes no site, e como sou leigo na área, não consigo resolver sem dar conflito, tentei até criar dois nomes e scripts e css para tudo, porém deu muitos conflitos de código e a semântica ficou horrível, eu sei que é possível criar mais de um com pequenos ajudstes no código, porém cheguei a conclusão de que sem ajuda eu não vou achar a resposta!

Como está:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como preciso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function mostra(theId){
    var theArray= new Array('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7', 'item8');
    for(i=0; i<theArray.length; i++){
        if(theArray[i] == theId){
            document.getElementById(theId).style.display='block';
        }else{
            document.getElementById(theArray[i]).style.display='none';
        }
    }
}
</script>
<script>
var SETTINGS = {
    navBarTravelling: false,
    navBarTravelDirection: "",
    navBarTravelDistance: 150
}

var colours = {
    0: "#00BAFF",
    1: "#32CD32",
    2: "#ECBB0C",
    3: "#40FEFF",
    4: "#14CC99",
    5: "#0082B2",
    6: "#7F4200",
    7: "#B25D7A",
    8: "#006B49",
    9: "#FF3400",
    10: "#00B27A",
    11: "#996B3D",
    12: "#CC7014",
    13: "#40FF8C",
    14: "#253A93",
    15: "#ECBB5E",
    16: "#125FB9",
    17: "#B9D912",
    18: "#99813D",
    19: "#867100",
}

document.documentElement.classList.remove("no-js");
document.documentElement.classList.add("js");

// Out advancer buttons

// the indicator
var pnIndicator = document.getElementById("pnIndicator");

var pnProductNav = document.getElementById("pnProductNav");
var pnProductNavContents = document.getElementById("pnProductNavContents");

pnProductNav.setAttribute("data-overflowing", determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav));


// Set the indicator
moveIndicator(pnProductNav.querySelector("[aria-selected=\"true\"]"), colours[0]);

// Handle the scroll of the horizontal container
var last_known_scroll_position = 0;
var ticking = false;

function doSomething(scroll_pos) {
    pnProductNav.setAttribute("data-overflowing", determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav));
}

pnProductNav.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;
    if (!ticking) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            doSomething(last_known_scroll_position);
            ticking = false;
        });
    }
    ticking = true;
});

pnProductNavContents.addEventListener(
    "transitionend",
    function() {
        // get the value of the transform, apply that to the current scroll position (so get the scroll pos first) and then remove the transform
        var styleOfTransform = window.getComputedStyle(pnProductNavContents, null);
        var tr = styleOfTransform.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") || styleOfTransform.getPropertyValue("transform");
        // If there is no transition we want to default to 0 and not null
        var amount = Math.abs(parseInt(tr.split(",")[4]) || 0);
        pnProductNavContents.style.transform = "none";
        pnProductNavContents.classList.add("pn-ProductNav_Contents-no-transition");
        // Now lets set the scroll position
        if (SETTINGS.navBarTravelDirection === "left") {
            pnProductNav.scrollLeft = pnProductNav.scrollLeft - amount;
        } else {
            pnProductNav.scrollLeft = pnProductNav.scrollLeft + amount;
        }
        SETTINGS.navBarTravelling = false;
    },
    false
);

// Handle setting the currently active link
pnProductNavContents.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
 var links = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".pn-ProductNav_Link"));
 links.forEach(function(item) {
  item.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
 })
 e.target.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
 // Pass the clicked item and it's colour to the move indicator function
 moveIndicator(e.target, colours[links.indexOf(e.target)]);
});

// var count = 0;
function moveIndicator(item, color) {
    var textPosition = item.getBoundingClientRect();
    var container = pnProductNavContents.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var distance = textPosition.left - container;
  var scroll = pnProductNavContents.scrollLeft;
    pnIndicator.style.transform = "translateX(" + (distance + scroll) + "px) scaleX(" + textPosition.width * 0.01 + ")";
 // count = count += 100;
 // pnIndicator.style.transform = "translateX(" + count + "px)";
 
    if (color) {
        pnIndicator.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}

function determineOverflow(content, container) {
    var containerMetrics = container.getBoundingClientRect();
    var containerMetricsRight = Math.floor(containerMetrics.right);
    var containerMetricsLeft = Math.floor(containerMetrics.left);
    var contentMetrics = content.getBoundingClientRect();
    var contentMetricsRight = Math.floor(contentMetrics.right);
    var contentMetricsLeft = Math.floor(contentMetrics.left);
  if (containerMetricsLeft > contentMetricsLeft && containerMetricsRight < contentMetricsRight) {
        return "both";
    } else if (contentMetricsLeft < containerMetricsLeft) {
        return "left";
    } else if (contentMetricsRight > containerMetricsRight) {
        return "right";
    } else {
        return "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

.pn-ProductNav_Wrapper {
 position: relative;
 padding: 0 11px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pn-ProductNav {
    /* Make this scrollable when needed */
    overflow-x: auto;
    /* We don't want vertical scrolling */
    overflow-y: hidden;
    /* For WebKit implementations, provide inertia scrolling */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    /* We don't want internal inline elements to wrap */
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* If JS present, let's hide the default scrollbar */
    .js & {
        /* Make an auto-hiding scroller for the 3 people using a IE */
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
        /* Remove the default scrollbar for WebKit implementations */
        &::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
        }
    }
 /* positioning context for advancers */
 position: relative;
 /*Crush the whitespace here*/
 font-size: 0;
}

.pn-ProductNav_Contents {
 float: left;
 transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
 position: relative;
}

.pn-ProductNav_Contents-no-transition {
 transition: none;
}

.pn-ProductNav_Link {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #888;
 /*Reset the font size*/
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 44px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 padding: 0 11px;
 & + & {
  border-left-color: #eee;
 }
 &[aria-selected="true"] {
  color: #111;
 }
}

.pn-ProductNav_Indicator {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 4px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: transparent;
 transform-origin: 0 0;
 transition: transform .2s ease-in-out, background-color .2s ease-in-out;
}


#caixas{
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 10px;
  
}
.conteudocaixas{
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.imagemcaixas{
 margin-top: 5px;
 width: 12.15%;
 max-width: 170px;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
}
.position_btcx{
 display: inline-block;
}
.button_cx{
 background: #fff;
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
  
.caixa1{
 margin: 0 0.5% 0 0.5%;
}
.caixa2{
 margin: 0 0.5% 0 0.5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="caixas">
    <div class="caixa1">
        <div class="pn-ProductNav_Wrapper">
            <nav id="pnProductNav" class="pn-ProductNav">
                <div id="pnProductNavContents" class="pn-ProductNav_Contents">
                    <a onclick="mostra('item1');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link" aria-selected="true">Galeria1</a>
                    <a onclick="mostra('item2');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Galeria2</a>
                    <a onclick="mostra('item3');" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Galeria3</a>
                    <span id="pnIndicator" class="pn-ProductNav_Indicator"></span>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div id="item1" style="display:block;">
                <div class="conteudocaixas">
                    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
                    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="item2" style="display:none;">
                <div class="conteudocaixas">
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="item3" style="display:none;">
                <div class="conteudocaixas">
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifiquei seu código, e usei apenas um comando em **JQuery**, que vi que estava incluído em seu código.

Primeiro o código **Javascript**, esqueça aquelas funções todas, use só isso:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    document.documentElement.classList.remove("no-js");
    document.documentElement.classList.add("js");

    $('.pn-ProductNav_Link').click(function() {
        // Remove a class active, de todos os itens do menu clicado
        $(this).parent().children().removeClass('active');

        // Adiciona a classe active, a esse menu clicado
        $(this).addClass('active');

        // Deixa invisível todos as seções de fotos dessa área
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("[item]").css('display', 'none');

        // Torna visível somente a área que tem o mesmo ID do item clicado
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("[item='" + $(this).attr('item') + "']").css('display', 'block');
    });
</script>
```

Depois o **CSS**, modifiquei poucas coisas. A principal mudança, foi pra realizar aquele efeito da linha a baixo do menu selecionado. Criei uma classe `active`, ao invés de criar um elemento. Essa classe manipula as bordas do item `a` selecionado, já com os efeitos de transição via CSS.

```
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }
    .pn-ProductNav_Wrapper {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 11px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .pn-ProductNav {
        /* Make this scrollable when needed */
        overflow-x: auto;
        /* We don't want vertical scrolling */
        overflow-y: hidden;
        /* For WebKit implementations, provide inertia scrolling */
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        /* We don't want internal inline elements to wrap */
        white-space: nowrap;
        /* If JS present, let's hide the default scrollbar */
        .js & {
            /* Make an auto-hiding scroller for the 3 people using a IE */
            -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
            /* Remove the default scrollbar for WebKit implementations */
            &::-webkit-scrollbar {
                display: none;
            }
        }
        /* positioning context for advancers */
        position: relative;
        /*Crush the whitespace here*/
        font-size: 0;
        height: 46px;
    }
    .pn-ProductNav_Contents {
        float: left;
        transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
        position: relative;
    }
    .pn-ProductNav_Contents-no-transition {
        transition: none;
    }
    .pn-ProductNav_Link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #888;
        /*Reset the font size*/
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 44px;
        padding: 0 11px;
        & + & {
            border-left-color: #eee;
        }
        &[aria-selected="true"] {
            color: #111;
        }
    }
    .pn-ProductNav_Link.active {
        border-bottom: 4px solid;
        border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 186, 255);
        transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
    }
    caixas{
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 10px;

    }
    .conteudocaixas{
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .imagemcaixas{
        margin-top: 5px;
        width: 12.15%;
        max-width: 170px;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .position_btcx{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .button_cx{
        background: #fff;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .caixa{
        margin: 0 0.5% 0 0.5%;
    }
</style>
```

Por fim o **HTML**. Retirei a repetição das imagens para economizar espaço aqui. Ficaria assim:

```
<div class="caixas">
    <div class="caixa">
        <div class="pn-ProductNav_Wrapper">
            <nav class="pn-ProductNav">
                <div class="pn-ProductNav_Contents">
                    <a item="1" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link active">Galeria1</a>
                    <a item="2" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Galeria2</a>
                    <a item="3" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Galeria3</a>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div item="1" style="display:block;">
                <div class="conteudocaixas">
                    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div item="2" style="display:none;">
                <div class="conteudocaixas">
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div item="3" style="display:none;">
                <div class="conteudocaixas">
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="caixa">
        <div class="pn-ProductNav_Wrapper">
            <nav class="pn-ProductNav">
                <div class="pn-ProductNav_Contents">
                    <a item="1" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link active">Galeria1</a>
                    <a item="2" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Galeria2</a>
                    <a item="3" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" class="pn-ProductNav_Link">Galeria3</a>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div item="1" style="display:block;">
                <div class="conteudocaixas">
                    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div item="2" style="display:none;">
                <div class="conteudocaixas">
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div item="3" style="display:none;">
                <div class="conteudocaixas">
                    <img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

De um modo geral, fiz de modo que a manipulação se desse em referência ao elemento clicado e não a `IDs`. A tag ID do HTML pressupõe que aquele elemento é único, o que no seu caso não é verdade. Dessa forma usando classes, a lógica é aplicada de forma homogênea a todos elementos e possíveis duplicatas. Sem contar a simplicidade da programação aplicada para resolver o problema. A seção é localizada através de um atributo personalizado criado no HTML, o atributo `item`. O `âncora` clicado e a `div` compartilham o mesmo valor, ligando assim um ao outro.

Resultado final:

[image: Imagem de Resultado Final]

Comment: Cara, para ficar perfeito só faltou o efeito sublinhado correndo e mudando de cor, mas ja me ajudou muito!

Comment: Como seria esse efeito? Porque o sublinhado muda de um pro outro. E a cor seria aleatória?

Comment: O efeito faz com que quando mude de aba a linha não some de um e aparece na outra, ela corre de uma para a outra.


No javascript tinha uma lista sequencial com as cores definidas, cada uma aba ele dava uma cor ligada a variavel colours, pra mim é um pouco útil a definição de cor em cada aba.

Comment: se conseguisse me ajudar eu ficaria grato, o efeito consegui aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/xY7tx/4845/

Comment: Outro mais simples, efeito está apenas em css, porém como Hover.
link: https://codepen.io/rm/pen/ldhon